# Why does sklearn linear regression give a non-zero intercept for a line passing through (0,0)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Given some data points for a line **y = 3x**:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
X = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
y = [[3],[6],[9],[12],[15]]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X,y)
```

then:

```
regr.predict([[6], [7], [8], [9], [10]])
```

gives, as expected:

```
array([[ 18.],
       [ 21.],
       [ 24.],
       [ 27.],
       [ 30.]])
```

and `regr.coef_` is 3, as expected. But why is `regr.intercept_` not 0?

```
regr.intercept_
array([ -3.55271368e-15])
```

Comment: It's 0 + rounding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a floating point problem -- the number is *very* close to 0.  You can use `numpy`'s built in testing suite to check

```
>>> from numpy.testing import assert_almost_equal
>>> assert_almost_equal(regr.intercept_, 0)
```

To answer *why* the number isn't zero, you can go down the following rabbit hole:

- sklearn uses `scipy.linalg.lstsq` to fit linear regression,
- `scipy.linalg.lstsq` uses `gelss` from `LAPACK` to find the least square solution to `Ax = b`,
- `gelss` uses the singular value decomposition of `A` to solve.

I would guess `gelss` is where the tiny bit of error was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

`-3.55271368e-15` can also be written `0.000 000 000 000 003 552 713`, so you could just consider that it is zero and a rounding error...

The rest is just supposition, because I did not read sklearn sources but the reason why it's not really zero could be

- `LinearRegression.fit()` has to solve a minimization problem (find `a` and `b` to minimize square error between `ax+b` model and dataset).
- To solve this, an iterative algoritm that converge to the solution is likely to be used (gradient descent?)
- Its end condition is probably something like `Stop when abs(error(step n) - error(step n+1)) < epsilon`. With epsilon being a fixed small value.

*Edit: 
That being said, this is no neural network.
I'm pretty sure that a linear (or polynomial for that matter) regression can be solved exactly by derivating the squared error expression. I find it strange that sklearn implemented it like this.*

Comment: linear regression can just be analytically solved in this case, no need for an iterative algorithm like you've described. rounding error explains the discrepancy, not gradient descent convergence.

Comment: Yes I wrote that already in the bottom of my answer... Maybe I should just delete the whole answer altogether.

Comment: I'd leave it, there's still good info in there. Didn't see your edit, sorry, I was just trying to point out that in this case, there's no way sklearn wouldn't use an analytical approach to solving linear regression.